# Maclaurin series of $\sin(2\pi x)$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

> Find the Maclaurin Series for $$f(x) = \sin ( 2 \pi x )$$ using the definition of a Maclaurin series.
>
> If $f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty c_{2n+1}x^{2n+1}$, give $c_{2n+1}$:
>
> > $\dfrac{2^{2n+1} \pi}{( 2n+1 )!}\;\;\;$*(incorrect)*
>
> What is the radius of convergence?
>
> > infinity$\;\;\;$*(correct)*

<sub>[(Original image on imgur)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ox7TW.jpg)</sub>

I've found the series, and I know how to find $c_n$ and the radius of convergence, but I don't understand how to find $c_{2n+1}$.

---

Comment: The easy way is to substitute in the Maclaurin series for $\sin t$, which you probably know. You can also proceed from the definition, the first derivative is $2\pi \cos(2\pi x)$, the second derivative is $-(2\pi)^2\sin(2\pi x)$, the third derivative is $-(2\pi)^3 \cos(2\pi x)$, and so on. There is cycling, apart from the $(2\pi)^k$ terms.

Comment: Since the comment button isn't working, I still don't understand how to find c2n+1 :(

Comment: Don't forget that the factor of $ \ \pi \ $ also gets raised to the same power in the repeated differentiations...  In regards to your question about the coefficients, what are the values of the successive derivatives at $ \ x = 0 \ $ ?